# How to build index from multiple columns and set to a column pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I´d like to learn how to data frame column as code maped from multiple columns.

In the partial example below I was trying what would could be a clumsy way folowing the path: get unique values as a temporary data frame; concatenate some prefix string to temp row number as a new column and them join the 2 data frames.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A3'],
                   'col2' : ['B1', 'B2', 'B1', 'B1'],
                   'value' : [100, 200, 300, 400],
                   })

tmp = df[['col1','col2']].drop_duplicates(['col1', 'col2'])


#   col1 col2
# 0   A1   B1
# 1   A2   B2
# 3   A3   B1
```

The first question is how to get 'temp' row number and its value to a tmp column?

And what is the clever pythonic way to achieve the result below from df?

```
dfnew = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A3'],
                   'col2' : ['B1', 'B2', 'B1', 'B1'],
                   'code' :  ['CODE0','CODE1', 'CODE0', 'CODE3'],
                   'value' : [100, 200, 300, 400],
                   })

    code col1 col2  value
0  CODE0   A1   B1    100
1  CODE1   A2   B2    200
2  CODE0   A1   B1    300
3  CODE3   A3   B1    400
```

thanks.

After the answers and just as an exercise I kept working on the non-pythonic version I had in mind with insights I got from great answers, and reached this:

```
tmp = df[['col1','col2']].drop_duplicates(['col1', 'col2'])

tmp.reset_index(inplace=True)

tmp.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)

tmp['code'] = tmp.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: 'code' + format(x, '04d'))

dfnew = pd.merge(df, tmp, on=['col1', 'col2'])
```

At the time of posting this question, I did not realize that would be nicer to have the index reset to have a fresh sequence instead of their original index numbers.

I tried some variations but I did not get how to chain 'reset_index' and 'drop' in just one command.

I´m starting to enjoy Python. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` on `df.index` with `['col1', 'col2']` using `transform('first')` and `map`

```
df.assign(
    code=df.index.to_series().groupby(
        [df.col1, df.col2]
    ).transform('first').map('CODE{}'.format)
)[['code'] + df.columns.tolist()]

    code col1 col2  value
0  CODE0   A1   B1    100
1  CODE1   A2   B2    200
2  CODE0   A1   B1    300
3  CODE3   A3   B1    400
```

---

***explanation***

```
# turn index to series so I can perform a groupby on it
idx_series = df.index.to_series()

# groupby col1 and col2 to establish uniqueness
idx_gb = idx_series.groupby([df.col1, df.col2])

# get first index value in each unique group
# and broadcast over entire group with transform
idx_tf = idx_gb.transform('first')

# map a format function to get desired string
code = idx_tf.map('code{}'.format)

# use assign to create new column
df.assign(code=code)
```

Comment: Hi @piRSquared, thank you, very fast solution indeed. An extra help?, how could I set 'groupby( [df.col1, df.col2]' to be done on a variable list of columns/fields ?  something like  'df.groupby[ [ fields list/series  ] ]'. I´d like to generalize it to a function with field names as base to code as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can first [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) of columns `col1` and `col2` where by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) find all duplicates:

```
df = df.sort_values(['col1', 'col2'])
mask = df.duplicated(['col1','col2'])
print (mask)
0    False
2     True
1    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Then use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) if need specify position of output column `code` with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) missing values. Last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'code', np.where(mask, np.nan, 'CODE' + df.index.astype(str)))
df.code = df.code.ffill()
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
    code col1 col2  value
0  CODE0   A1   B1    100
1  CODE1   A2   B2    200
2  CODE0   A1   B1    300
3  CODE3   A3   B1    400
```

Comment: Sure, btw, I think my code is faster, you can check it. ;)

Comment: ok, I´ll try to build a comparison test here with the real data frame. thank you.

Comment: Give me know, I am really interested. Because obviously `groupby` is slow.

Comment: your solution is the second fastest for some tests I did here. I used my data with aprox. 150.000 records and It gets very close to piRSquared solution when I remove the sort at the end. Is that really necessary? The concat solution was the slowest.

Comment: No, sort_index in the end is not necessary, only nicer output ;)

Answer (score 2):

> How to get 'temp' row number and its value to a tmp column?

Value column is not propagating because you filter it out at the beginning: `df[['col1','col2']]`. Hence, this is fixed by changing it to `tmp = df.drop_duplicates(['col1', 'col2'])`.

Index is preserved in the index column, if you want to copy it explicitly into data column, just do `tmp['index'] = tmp.index`.

> What is the clever pythonic way to achieve the result below from df?

I do not know if it is particularly clever or not, as this is subjective, but one way of achieving that is

```
pd.concat([gr.assign(code='CODE{}'.format(min(gr.index))) for _, gr in df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])])
```

Finally, to achieve the result in a form you specified, you can add `.sort_index()` and `[['code', 'col1', 'col2', 'value']]` to the above, in order to specify ordering of columns. Giving:

```
newdf = pd.concat([gr.assign(code='CODE{}'.format(min(gr.index))) for _, gr in df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])]).sort_index()[['code', 'col1', 'col2', 'value']]
```

Possible performance bottleneck may be `groupby` and `concat` which may matter if you operate on large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `df` DataFrame like this:

```
    state       year    population
0   California  2000    33871648
1   California  2010    37253956
2   New York    2000    18976457
3   New York    2010    19378102
4   Texas       2000    20851820
5   Texas       2010    25145561
```

you can create indexes from `state` and `year` columns with:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['state','year'])
```

which will give you dataframe with multi-index constructed from columns `state` and `year`:

[image]

**Accessing Multindexed dataframe**

```
df['California',2000]
Result: 33871648

df[:,2010]
Result:
state
California    37253956
New York      19378102
Texas         25145561
dtype: int64


pop.loc['California':'New York']
Result:
state       year
California  2000    33871648
            2010    37253956
New York    2000    18976457
            2010    19378102
dtype: int64
```